# toggle edit buttons with save and cancel buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, button, toggle

I want to change the button when it's clicked. Initial there's only one "Edit" button. After I click it, it will become a "Save" button and I also want to show a "Cancel" button next to it. 
How can I do that? I have the code below.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script class="jsbin" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <meta charset=utf-8 />
    <title>demo by roXon</title>
    <!--[if IE]>
      <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    </head>

    <body>
    <button data-text="Save">Edit</button>
    <p>Hello</p>
    <p style="display: none">Good Bye</p>

<script>
$("button").click(function(){
    $(this).nextUntil('button').toggle();


    var btnText = $(this).text();
    $(this).text( $(this).data('text') );
    $(this).data('text', btnText );
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why don't you simply have three buttons with ids (edit, save, cancel) and then change them as needed, instead of using paragraphs and data functions?

Comment: @j08691 Do you have an example I can take a look at?

Comment: yes http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/JbZnf/

Comment: @j08691 Good one! But what if I have 3 groups of these buttons on one page? Do I need to give them different id and write the script separately for them? Sorry for being a jquery newbie...

Comment: Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/JbZnf/1/

Comment: It's almost perfect! How to switch to "Edit" mode when I click on "Save" as well? @j08691

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/JbZnf/2/. Do you want me to post this as an answer?

Comment: Awesome! Please do that!

Comment: @j08691 Can you help me with that? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11526200/switch-content-jquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest a layout and jQuery like this **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/JbZnf/2/)**.

**jQuery**

```
$('.edit').click(function() {
    $(this).hide();
    $(this).siblings('.save, .cancel').show();
});
$('.cancel').click(function() {
    $(this).siblings('.edit').show();
    $(this).siblings('.save').hide();
    $(this).hide();
});
$('.save').click(function() {
    $(this).siblings('.edit').show();
    $(this).siblings('.cancel').hide();
    $(this).hide();
});
```

​

**HTML**

```
<form>
    <div>
    <input class="edit" type="button" value="Edit" />
    <input class="save" type="button" value="Save" /> 
    <input class="cancel" type="button" value="Cancel" />
    </div>
    <div>
    <input class="edit" type="button" value="Edit" />
    <input class="save" type="button" value="Save" /> 
    <input class="cancel" type="button" value="Cancel" />
    </div>
    <div>
    <input class="edit" type="button" value="Edit" />
    <input class="save" type="button" value="Save" /> 
    <input class="cancel" type="button" value="Cancel" />
    </div>
</form>
```

​
**CSS**

```
.save, .cancel {
display:none;
}​
```

Comment: Instead of using $(this), you can cache it and use. This will improve performance (or you can use chaning facility, $(this).hide().siblings('.save, .cancel').show();

Answer (score 3):

you can add a new button for the cancel and just hide it as you need.
you can follow the [demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/WdezH/4/)

here is the code in case you need it:

```
<button id='EditSave' data-text="Save">Edit</button>
<button id='Cancel' data-text="Cancel" style="display:none;">Cancel</button>
    <p>Hello</p>
    <p style="display: none">Good Bye</p>​

$("#EditSave").click(function(){
    var btnText = $(this).text();
    if(btnText == 'Edit')
    {
        $(this).text('Save');
        $('#Cancel').show();
    }
    else
    {
        $(this).text('Edit');
        $('#Cancel').hide();
    }
});

$('#Cancel').click(function(){
    $(this).hide();
    $('#EditSave').text('Edit');
});
​
```

Comment: It's a good one. But what if I have more than one group of buttons on the same page? Then I have to give each one a difference ID right? Is there an easier way to tackle that?

Comment: if you give me the html of what you mean, i will be able to help you